# Value option for optional parameters in F#?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a static method with an optional argument:

```ml
open System

type Random with
  static member Sequence(?seed : int) =
    let seed = defaultArg seed 0
    seq {
      let r = new Random(seed)
      while true do
        yield r.Next()
    }
```

I noticed that there is a function called `defaultValueArg`:

```ml
open System

type Random with
  static member Sequence(?seed : int) =
    let seed = defaultValueArg seed 0 // <---
    seq {
      let r = new Random(seed)
      while true do
        yield r.Next()
    }
```

However, this code gives a type error:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>
> ```
> ''a voption'
> ```
>
> but here has type
>
> ```
> 'int option'
> ```

Is there a way to use a value option for an optional parameter in F#?

Comment: This is a language suggestion: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was said in the comments, this is not possible yet but there is a language suggestion.

An alternative to have optional parameters without allocating an option is to use C#-style optional parameters. This is done by explicitly adding the attributes that the C# compiler would insert for you if you wrote `(int seed = 0)` in C#:

```ml
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Random with
  static member Sequence([<Optional; DefaultParameterValue 0>] seed : int) =
    seq {
      let r = new Random(seed)
      while true do
        yield r.Next()
    }
```

Comment: Neat trick. Does F# code understand these attributes?

Comment: @sdgfsdh Yes, this parameter will also be treated as optional by an F# caller.